# Does MOXy support non-string @XmlID in version 2.6.0?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

According to https://gist.github.com/VineetReynolds/5108580, JAXB Spec requires element annotated with `@XmlID` to be a `String`. This hasn't been enforced by MOXy in versions *2.5.x*. 
With version *2.6.0*, however, it seems it's not supported anymore.

```
[Exception [EclipseLink-50016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: Property [id] has an XmlID annotation but its type is not String.]**strong text**
```

Is this a wanted behavior, or an unwanted regression?

What is the right way to avoid such error when migrating from MOXy *2.5.x*?
Is it to use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` as described in this post [Marshaling a long primitive type using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053063/marshaling-a-long-primitive-type-using-jaxb), which also affects the way how the object itself (and its ID) gets serialized to JSON (e.g., id field of type `Long` becomes a json string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is still supported. In 2.6.0 it is not supported by default, but must be enabled via `@XmlIDExtension` annotation.

https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.6.php

Just annotate given field with `@XmlIDExtension`. It is also possible to specify system property `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.annotation.xml-id-extension` to override default behavior globally.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason I was unable to google for the information in the release notes.