# JAVA WEBSERVICE : Unmarshalling Error: For input string: ""

Tags: java, unmarshalling

I'm running via SoapUI a webservice.
With the following request,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ofic="http://www.myserver.com/mywebService/">
   <soapenv:Header>
  <ofic:headerRequest>
     <timeStampRequest>2017-11-07</timeStampRequest>
     <username>xxxxxx</username>
     <password>xxxxxx</password>
  </ofic:headerRequest>
  </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ofic:contract>
         <contractNo></contractNo>
      </ofic:contract>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i'm obtaining this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: For input string: ""</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The attribute "contractNo"  is type "Long", and it can't have a null value. I was trying to validate the value of "contractNo", but it seems that this unmarshalling error fires before the validation of this attribute.

Is there a way to trap this unmarshalling error , in order to show a different message?

Thanks in advance!!!

***(...three hours later + a horrible headache ...)***

**SOLUTION**

In the class "Contract" i put this:

```
@NotNull(message="cannot be null")
@XmlElement(required = false,nillable=true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=long.class, value=XMLLongAdapter.class)
protected long contractNo;
```

XMLLongAdapter.class  was built based on this post --> [Marshaling a long primitive type using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053063/marshaling-a-long-primitive-type-using-jaxb)

And that is, i can validate the null entry for the attribute "contractNo"

I hope it helps.